# Logarithm identity in complex analysis

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, logarithms

Does identity $\log(z^2)= 2\log(z)$ hold for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$?

First I tried:

$$2\log(z)= 2\log (r) + 2 i \operatorname{Arg}(z) + 4k\pi i, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\log(z^2)= \log(r^2 e^{2 i \phi})= 2\log(r) + i \operatorname{Arg}(z^2) + 2 k \pi i , k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

where $\operatorname{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$.

If we let $z=i$, then  $\log(i^2) = 0 + i\operatorname{Arg}(-1) + 2k \pi i= i \pi+ 2k \pi i$

and  $2 \log(i)=  i \pi  +4 k \pi i  $,
which is different.

On the other hand, I found  somewhere that $\log(z w )= \log(z) + \log(w)$, and if we apply it here, we get $\log(z^2)= 2 \log(z)$.

Now I don't know what to conclude and  in the case that identity holds, do we need some assumptions on the branch of logarithm? Does it hold  for the main branch i.e. $\operatorname{Log}$? I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: If you are using some branch of log, so that $\log$ inverts the exponential function, then $\log(z^2) = 2\log(z)$ whenever both sides make sense because the exponential of both sides is $z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need some assumptions on the branch of the logarithm. The equation $\log\left(z^2\right) = 2\log(z)$ does not always hold.

Let's take your example and let $z=i$. Consider the branch defined by $\theta \in \left(\dfrac{3\pi}{4}, \dfrac{11\pi}{4}\right)$. We have
$$
\log\left(i^2\right) = \log(-1) = \log\left(1e^{i\pi}\right) = \log(1) + i\pi = i\pi
$$

Since $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \equiv \dfrac{5\pi}{2} \pmod{2\pi}$ (extending modulo congruences to real numbers), we have

$$
2\log(i) = 2\log\left(1e^{i5\pi/2}\right) = 2\left(\log(1) + i\dfrac{5\pi}{2}\right) = 5\pi i.
$$

Obviously, they are not equal, disproving the equation in question.

However, the equation does hold if $\theta \in \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{9\pi}{4}\right)$. I am sure you can prove that for yourself.

> On the other hand, I found  somewhere that $\log(z w )= \log(z) + \log(w)$, and if we apply it here, we get $\log(z^2)= 2 \log(z)$.

For any branch of $\log(z)$ and if $z,w \neq 0$, then $\log(zw) = \log(z) + \log(w) + i2\pi n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The formula I quoted in gray above does hold for modulo $2\pi i$. Note that the $\exp$ complex function is periodic on $2\pi i$, meaning you would have to choose which logarithm to take.

> Does it hold  for the main branch i.e. $\operatorname{Log}$?

If you mean "main branch" as in the principal branch $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$, then no. Take $z=-i$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, equality really holds for $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{9 \pi}{4})$.  Just one question: I know that $log(z)$ is defined as $log(z)= log|z| + i Arg(z) + 2 k \pi i$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ represents the branch of logarithm and $Arg(z) \in (-\pi, \pi)$. How do you chose e.g.  the interval $ (\frac{3 \pi}{4}, \frac{11 \pi}{4})$? What is the argument in your principal branch  $(Logz)$ and how is argument related to branch here?  (According to definition that I wrote, I suppose that the intervals are of the form $(-\pi +2k\pi, \pi +2k\pi)$, so I don't understand why is different interval chosen)

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant, but I'm not familiar with that logarithm definition. I was going by the definition "$\log(z) = \log|z| + i\operatorname{arg}(z)$" where choosing a branch for the argument makes the logarithm single-valued. I was never using the principal branch when I let $z=i$. I came up with those branches because when I was rewriting $-1$ and $i$, I wanted to see if I could come up with a polar form such that their angles were elements of a certain branch, if that makes sense. (I also did something similar in my notes a long time ago.) @user122

Comment: If you suppose the intervals are of the form $\left(-\pi+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi\right)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then calculating $\log\left(i^2\right) = \log(\exp(i\pi (2k+1)))$ would not make sense because the open endpoints of that interval are odd multiples of $\pi$. It is true that $\log\left(i^2\right) = \log(\exp(i\pi (2k+1)))$ for some integer $k$, but that is assuming you are working under a branch that includes the argument $\pi (2k+1)$ so that the logarithm is single-valued. @user122